# verilog asynchronous clock design question

Tags: verilog

I need to design a module that has three inputs
1- system clk with pretty high freq
2- async clk inp P
3- async clk inp Q
P and Q have 50 % duty cycle each and their frequencies are closed enough and they have phase difference. Design the module to generate these outputs
1- PeqQ goes high if periods of p and q are the same
2- PleQ goes high id period of P is less than the period of Q
3- PgeQ goes high if period of p is larger than the period of Q

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is a phase frequency detector.
In the below figure replace A,B with your clocks P,Q.
[image]